# What is the difference between proving an equation versus verifying LHS = RHS?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-proofs

I am referring to the book `Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics (3rd Edition)` . In the chapter 4.4, I came across the following example -

### Prove that for every two sets A and B, (A ∪ B) − (A ∩ B) = (A − B) ∪ (B − A).

The solution said that to prove the above statement is true, we need to show that LHS ⊆ RHS and RHS ⊆ LHS.

My question is that, can I answer the question by simplify both, LHS and RHS, to show LHS = RHS? Will that be enough to answer the question?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be hesitant to answer before knowing what you mean by "simplify both LHS and RHS"

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I meant to use various properties such as set subtraction definition that is defined by only using set operators, and then use De Morgan's law to simplify each side.

Comment: You don't "prove an equation". You are asked to prove that the sets described in those two ways are the same set. You may or may not be able to do that by manipulating the descriptions. That's the essence of @PrincessEev 's comment. Even if that kind of proof is possible, it will teach you less than the approach suggested.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah I added "Prove that..." by myself as it wasn't a part of the question. Could you explain what you mean by "You may or may not be able to do that by manipulating the descriptions". In which cases I would not be able to manipulate the descriptions?

Comment: @ParthGupta I don't want to spend the time inventing a problem at this level where you have to think about the meaning rather than manipulate some descriptions algebraically. I don't know whether manipulation works here since I haven't tried it.

Comment: To show $U_{left}=U_{right}$, it is valid to show $U_{left}=U_1=U_2=U_3 = \cdots = U_n = U_{right}$, which is one way of framing your "simplify each side" or "manipulate the descriptions" idea, provided you have tools to show $U_{left}=U_1$ and $U_1=U_2$ and so on.

Comment: @angryavian That helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting at two different ways of proving that two sets are equal.

One way to show two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal is to show that $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$.

Another way is to apply the laws of set algebra (e.g. De Morgan's law) and definitions (e.g. definition of set difference). In this way, you're "simplifying" both sides.

In general, both of these are valid ways of proving two sets are equal. In this case, I would suggest trying both ways. The first way will give you more intuition in understanding the definition of set differences, unions and intersections. The second way will help you practice utilising the laws of set algebra (in particular, you may have to utilise distributivity so your expression will get a bit complicated).

Comment: I see. So basically, the approach that the book uses, intends to introduce another way of proving things. Right?

Comment: Actually, both of these methods are standard ways of proving that two sets are equal. One could argue that the first method (the "double inclusion method") is more important to learn!